# Ask for multiple id's with the same data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check for a data attribute in multiple list items.

My HTML:

```
<ul id="year">
  <li id="2006">2006</li>
  <li id="2007">2007</li>
  <li id="2008">2008</li>
  <li id="2009">2009</li>
  <li id="2010">2010</li>
  <li id="2011">2011</li>
  <li id="2012">2012</li>
  <li id="2013">2013</li>
  <li id="2014">2014</li>
</ul>
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
jQuery('#year li').click(function()
{
    var year = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    if ((jQuery(this).data('state') === undefined) || (jQuery(this).data('state') == "off"))
    {
        jQuery(this).data('state', 'on');
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery(this).data('state', 'off');
    }
});
```

Now i am trying to check if there are any list items where the "state" == "on"
Like this:

```
if ((jQuery('#year li').data('state') == "on"))
```

But it does not seem to be working...

EDIT: So i tried all the different snippets you gave me: none of them worked so i made a simple for loop that looks in every list point itself:

```
    for ( var y = 2006, l = 2015; y < l; y++ )
    {
    if ((jQuery('#year #'+y).data('state') == "on"))
    {
        alert('data found');
    }
```

Another problem was that i didnt had any event before my code!
Thanks for the support!

Comment: did you notice my answer? isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: Yeah, i saw your answer, but this is way too complicated for me! But i found a simplet solution that works just the same.

Comment: ok, up to you. it's a single line of code though, maybe try looking again (everything else is boilerplate to show how it works)

Comment: @Amit , look this line of text does not make sence to me:    
    this.dataset.state = this.dataset.state === 'off' ? 'on' : 'off';

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `jQuery('#year li')` will return an array of jquery objects.

you will need to loop `each`  one

```
$('#year li').each(function () {
    if ((jQuery(this).data('state') === "on")){
        alert("on state found");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) then check `length` property

```
var list = jQuery('#year li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('state') == "on"; 
    //OR, using native dataset
    //return this.dataset.state == 'on'
});

if (list.length){
   //li with state on exits
}
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out the DOM approach: `this.dataset.state == 'on'`

Comment: Can you add a snippet?

Comment: Your function returns this:
[Object object]

Comment: @Aztekke, Yes filter returns jQuery object, you need to check its `length` property

Comment: the length is "0" no matter if the status is off or on

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work for you is that jQuery doesn't store data values in the "standard" element dataset. You can acheive your goal by doing that yourself:

```js
$('#year li').click(function() {
  this.dataset.state = this.dataset.state === 'off' ? 'on' : 'off';
  if($('#year li[data-state="on"]').length > 0) {
    alert('Found!')
  }
});
```

```css
#year li[data-state="on"] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="year">
  <li id="2006">2006</li>
  <li id="2007">2007</li>
  <li id="2008">2008</li>
  <li id="2009">2009</li>
  <li id="2010">2010</li>
  <li id="2011">2011</li>
  <li id="2012">2012</li>
  <li id="2013">2013</li>
  <li id="2014">2014</li>
</ul>
```